# Node.js Busboy parse fields and files seperatly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload

I was wondering if it is possible to get Busboy to parse the fields and files separately. (I have removed `bodyParser` as you can fill the hard drive with temp files very easily.)

For instance - middleware which parsers post fields (used on all POST requests)

```
if (req.method === 'POST') {
    var form = new busboy({ headers: req.headers, limit: { files: 0 } });

    form.on('field', function (fieldname, val, valTruncated, keyTruncated) {
        req.params.body[fieldname] = val;
    });
    form.on('finish', function () {
        next();
    });
    return req.pipe(form);

} else { next(); }
```

Then on upload pages use the following, which uses Busboy to get the posted files.

```
app.post('/fm/file/upload/:folder', function (req, res) {
    var isFrame = helpers.toBool(req.param('frame'), false),
        uploadService = fmUploadService.create(),
        userId = res.locals.info.User.Id,
        folder = helpers.toInt(req.param('folder', 0));

uploadService.processUploads(userId, folder, req, res, function (uploadError, allowedAccess, files) {
        if (uploadError) {
            if (req.xhr) {
                res.status(500);
                res.json(uploadError);
            } else {
                res.render('filemanager/file_upload.jade', { actionUrl: '/fm/file/upload/' + folder, tempData: files, isFrame: isFrame, err: uploadError });
            }
            return;
        }
        else if (req.xhr) {
            res.status(200);
            res.json(files);
            return;
        }
        res.render('filemanager/file_upload.jade', { actionUrl: '/fm/file/upload/' + folder, tempData: files, isFrame: isFrame, err: null });
    });
});
```

Currently files will always be 0 as Busboy has already run within the middleware.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same use case, want to parse files in my model, but catch the fields as middleware to populate the req.body before hitting the routes.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this. Any updates?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but in Express 4, Multer handles the file uploads separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
form.on('finish', function () {
    next();
});`
```

try it with

```
form.on('end', function () {
    next();
});`
```